# Adding a character to the first item when using "join" with jquery

Tags: jquery, join, jquery-isotope, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 and jquery isotope to set up filters for isotope with the following code.

```
$("#selectFilter").select2({
        placeholder: "Keywords",
        width: 250
}).on("change", function() {  
var singleValues = $("#selectFilter").select2("val").join(",.");
$container.isotope({ filter: singleValues });

});
```

It works except that the problem is with the first val selected. It needs to have a '.' before the value and I'm not sure how to do that with join, being a newbie at this. I've tried prepend but not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `var singleValues = '.' + $("#selectFilter").select2("val").join(",.");` ?

Comment: The simple solution I overlooked, thanks! Another question, if I have one select option that I do not want a '.' before, is their a way to prevent that one "val" form getting the '.'? Slice maybe?